# Furnace heat duct for basement

Tags: furnace, exhaust-vent, heat, register

I'm trying to install a heat exhaust vent on the side of the drywall in the basement, see pic. The issue is that the the register is too small for the boot. This is normal if the exhaust is in the floor but not so great on the side of the wall. 
The question is how to attach the boot to the register to avoid air leaks... Basically to do it right.[image: see pic here]

Comment: Cut the seams of the 4 corners so you can taper the duct to fit your register. Wrap it with duct tape. (not the handy man tape, actual duct tape with the foil backing)

Comment: @phaelax z , make that an answer I can’t tell how far the size is but I do cut square ducts since the size is off. The foil tape is the only way to tape duct work. The other stuff is for tying your brother up , but I haven’t done that for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find a piece of duct at the big box store to extend the boot to the wall. You'll need to trim it with a good set of tin snips. When you trim it leave some tabs so the register screws have something to bite into instead of just drywall. Get a larger register that better matches up to the duct. If you can't get the duct to line up with the register then see if you can rotate the boot and cut the duct at an angle. If you don't do a great job then get some foil duct tape to cover any gaps.

Comment: Thanks! Ended up cutting 3 corners of the boot and bending two sides in to get a snug fit over the register. Used some pliers to get the corners together and foil tape to tape on the outside. Cut two rectangular pieces of metal sheet and attached them on the sides of the boot (opening and closing register will be an issue later if the screws are too close) for the register screws to bite into later.